# Can I create and use page on blazor library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

If I use `@page "/test"` in my Blazor library and publish in nuget and add this package to my Blazor app, does page `/test` work?

Can I navigate to `/test` in my Blazor app? (like this: `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/test");`)

Thanks for answers))

Comment: Try it and let us know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the router to see the library assembly so it can trawl it for classes with the `RouteAttribute`.

Here's an example:

`Routes.razor`

```cs
<CascadingAuthenticationState>

    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="_additionalAssemblies">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
            </RouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
    </Router>

</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code {
    private List<System.Reflection.Assembly> _additionalAssemblies = new()
    {
        typeof(MyLibrary.AnyClass).Assembly,
    };
}
```